# Msysgit for windows - Cheetah plugin not showing?

Tags: windows, git

I recently installed git 1.8 for windows and chose to install the cheetah plugin for windows explorer shell integration. However, I don't see any options pop-up in the right click menu. Is there something I have to do to get it to appear in the right-click menu?

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah
```

Do:

```
regsvr32 git_shell_ext64.dll
```

This at least gets you 3 context menus (don't know if cheetah plugin cause I never saw it :-)

Is this a bug or what? I thought installer should be doing this (things like registering DLLs).

P.S. of course you have to run this command as Administrator.

P.P.S. Start | Run, type cmd.exe, then RIGHT CLICK cmd.exe and select "run as administrator". Apparently you also have to restart Windows Explorer to see the context menu.

Comment: Didn't work for me, tried with admin permission but still no option on Windows Explorer...

Comment: You have to open a windows command prompt (Git bash may work too) and navigate to the directory. "regsvr32" is a terminal command.

Comment: Start | Run, type cmd.exe, then RCLICK cmd.exe and select "run as administrator"

Comment: which menus does it get you?

Comment: I don't have that folder in my git installation (Git-1.8.3-preview20130601). The plugin worked the first time, but never again since I rebooted. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @GuillermoMoscoso: well look for the DLL above with smth like Voidtools Everything (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_(software)) and register that DLL

Comment: I believe you also need to restart explorer before it will show up in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Cheetah plugin seems to be broken in Git-1.8.3-preview20130601 on some systems (including mine). Re-registering .dll file as suggested didn't helped. The way I fixed it is:

1. Install older version - Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201 with Cheetah
   plugin.
2. While updating to Git-1.8.3-preview20130601 deselect context
   menu integration (no worries, it won't uninstall a plugin).

Answer (score 0):

The registry entry is separate for when you right click on a folder icon versus right clicking on space inside a folder.

If memory serves "Cheetah" only works with the former.

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/3d9596b/.cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Windows 7 with Git-1.8.3-preview20130601 version.

Supposedly when you select the Cheetah plugin on install it also installs the git-gui and gitk tools as well, but these were not showing up in the right click menu either.

After adding the path to the git cmd folder I at least got git-gui and gitk  to be available. ie add to your PATH variable:

"path to git directory install"\cmd